# Where to find a Path Integral treatment of 1D Quantum Heisenberg model or Quantum Spin Chain?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, path-integral, spin-models, spin-chains

All:

Where to find a Path Integral treatment of 1D Quantum Heisenberg model or Quantum Spin Chain?

I would like to find a detailed calculation of path amplitude in such situation. I did some google search, can not find a good paper or book on this subject.

Can anyone provide some help?

Comment: Fradkin's book "Fields Theories of Condensed Matter Physics" (Chapter 7) and/or Auerbach's book "Interacting Electrons and Quantum Magnetism" (Chapter 10)

Comment: @RubenVerresen Thank you. I will take a look of those books. For each path in Quantum Heisenberg Model (which means, a configuration of spin chain),  do you know if those books calculate path amplitude for  each path ?